# How to Insert Image into Jtable by Netbean Builder

Tags: java, image, jtable, cell

I designed 1 JTable by using Netbean Builder So how to create image to the table.
this is capture of code customizer and as u see there is no name for array row data and array column data.

[image]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to provide `Icon` or `ImageIcon` as the class type of given columns and `JTable` will render it for you

Within the default table editor for NetBeans, you can set the column class type, simply make it `Icon.class` or `ImageIcon.class`

Start by right clicking on your table in the design view and choosing "Customize Code"

[image]

In the editor, select "custom property" from the drop down box next to the code block you want to change...

[image]

Change the columns that require pictures to use `javax.swing.Icon.class`...

[image]